# Create seperate index corresponding to rows where condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I bet there's a simple answer to my question, but I'm struggling to figure it out based on just the Pandas documentation.

I have a large dataframe with ~20,000 rows and 14 columns. I need to find the indices where a certain regex expression is contained in one of the rows. So for a very simple example:

```
    label1    label2
0   cat       dog
1   bird      monkey
2   elephant  bobcat
```

When I search for 'cat', I'd like to get a series, list, some sort of iterable that looks like

```
0
2
```

How would you do that with pandas? I could do this 2-3 times a second on datasets of 20,000 or larger, so speed is really important here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how fast this can perform on your dataset.

```
df.applymap(lambda x: 'cat' in x).sum(1).nonzero()
Out[12]: (array([0, 2], dtype=int64),)
```